# iPhone 6 backlight issue, burn-in

Tags: display, iphone, warranty

I bought an iPhone 6 64GB in Space Gray from 5th avenue NY 14 days ago. I can see a grayish area at the top right corner, near to the charge display. It's hard notice in full brightness, but noticeable in low brightness which annoys me a lot. I know it will be tough to make apple genius understand but still can't live with it. I want to replace my phone. Will this one be covered by warranty policy? I have a slight hairlike scratch on the display.

Comment: Take it back - keep your thumb over the scratch when explaining the problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [iPhone warranty in the US doesn't cover physical damage](http://www.apple.com/legal/warranty/products/ios-warranty-document-us.html) or cosmetic issues. The scratch will likely be judged that way unless it interferes with a function like multi touch.

Similarly, the return policy / window might be your best bet - especially if the LCD quality is clearly different than the rest of the display phones. Just because a light scratch happened - if there's a problem with the overall display, I would assume you'd be able to request an exchange / repair / warranty service to address the backlight and not the scratch.

If Apple's repair option fixes the scratch too, so be it - that's their issue and not yours IMO.

Lastly, get in sooner rather than later. Also, if you didn't buy the phone outright - be sure your carrier is OK issuing a second subsidy before returning the phone.

Sorry this isn't simple - but you've got multiple aspects to a repair/return to consider.

Comment: the scratch is very minor and it has clearly nothing to do with the backlight.  I'm going for exchange very soon. thanks for your valuable thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a light scratch and the burn-in was there from day one, then Apple shouldn't have any reason not to exchange it for you.

Comment: I don't have a cracked screen. And the back light issue came with the packaging, from the very first day.

Comment: Sorry, thought you said "crack" not "scratch". Is it a really deep scratch? Apple might take it back anyway if the screen was burned-in from day one.

Comment: not at all, the scratch is really hard to notice! very minor. That upper right portion is bit warmer from very first day. it's noticeable at low brightness.

Comment: I'm really disappointed with apple's recent build quality. At least it's not desirable with a 820$ device.

Comment: Then there's really no reason why Apple shouldn't take it back or repair it then. Over time iPhones get light scratches and without a screen protector there's not a lot you can do to avoid it.

Comment: exactly. after replacement I will get one. I've seen many others complaining with same issues, warmer/grayish header portion over net. *sigh*

Comment: I changed my answer